# Android ViewHolder pattern with programmatically added views

Tags: android

I'm creating a FrameLayout and then I add two Views (an ImageView and a TextView ).

My code on getView() :

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView1;

    int new_width = wid/2;
    int textview_id=0;

    FrameLayout frame_layout = new FrameLayout(mContext);  // Instantiate the parent
    frame_layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    textView1 = new TextView(mContext); textView1.setId(position); 
    textView1.setText("Set Wallpaper");
    textView1.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.set_wallpaper_colors));
    textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView1.setTypeface(textView1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);


    FrameLayout.LayoutParams textview_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textview_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;


    FrameLayout.LayoutParams imageview_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            new_width -5, new_width -5 );


        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(new_width - 5, new_width -5));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    frame_layout.addView(imageView, imageview_params);
    frame_layout.addView(textView1, textview_params);

    return frame_layout;
}
```

How should I change it to use the ViewHolder class. There isn't a layout to inflate.

Comment: You can use the holder pattern in either way. You can inflate from an xml or create views dynamically. Post your entire getView method, so we can check it.

Comment: @Tim ok I have posted the code

Answer (score 0):

With your code it should be something like this

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView1;
    ImageView imageView1;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int row, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    FrameLayout frame_layout = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    if (frame_layout == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = new  TextView(mContext);
        holder.imageView1 = new ImageView(mContext);

        frame_layout.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) frame_layout.getTag();    
    }

    holder.textView1.setText("Set Wallpaper");
    holder.textView1.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.set_wallpaper_colors));
    holder.textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.textView1.setTypeface(holder.textView1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams textview_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textview_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams imageview_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        new_width -5, new_width -5 );

    holder.imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    holder.imageView1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    holder.imageView1.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    frame_layout.addView(holder.imageView1, imageview_params);
    frame_layout.addView(holder.textView1, textview_params);

    return frame_layout;
}
```

Comment: I'm working on your code. I'm confused with `holder.imageview_params` and `holder.textview_params`. I have edited my answer and added my code can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: Those lines I just copied from your code, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is just a pointer in the correct way to do it following your code, I shouldn't have to write your program for you?

Comment: Shouldn't you only call `addView()` in your `if()` statement, when the views are being created? Otherwise you're gonna be trying to re-add the views when the `convertView` is recycled, which is going to throw an `IllegalStateException` (specified child already has a parent).